# SQL Server 2008 permission for View Dependencies

Tags: sql-server, database-permissions

I would like to enable a SQL server user with read-only access to a DB the ability to view object dependencies. As a sysadmin I can select a table in SSMS and view any dependent objects (views, SPROCs, etc). My read-only users can see very few or none of these dependencies. I have already granted view definition but that didn't do it.

Does anyone know if there is a SQL server permission for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`VIEW OBJECT DEFINITION` granted on the relevant objects, or `VIEW ANY DEFINITION`. Note that the permission covers more than *just* dependencies and allows the grantee to view the *entire* definition of the object (source of a stored procedure, original query of a view, table definition etc etc.

If you want a more granular restriction you would have to customize it via a stored procedure that returns the dependencies and is code-signed to have the proper permissions, but this way users *must* use your procedure to view the dependencies (ie. the SSMS and alike tools *won't* work).